# How to create or modify the google maps controls?s

Tags: user-interface, api, google-maps, user-controls

I wonder how sites like trulia.com and fotocasa.com customized the google maps ui for their website

ex1:
http://www.trulia.com/for_sale/Pinecrest,FL/x_map/#for_sale/Pinecrest,FL/x_map/2_p/

Answer (score 0):

They created custom controls for their maps (think custom html elements overlayed on the map), which is explained with examples in the Google Maps API v3 ([click here](http://code.google.com/intl/en/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/controls.html#CustomControls)).